# why if statement isn't looking for a variable in global scope

Tags: javascript, scoping

I am trying to understand scoping in JS.Here i have an example which has a variable in global scope called `check`.It has a truthy value i mean `1`.Then inside a function called `main` which `doesn't have a variable called check` but has an `if statement` which checks whether there is a check variable or not ,upon which it reassign another value to check variable.Then prints it out.if i use

```
if(check){}
```

it prints undefined.*Here i have some questions*:

**1.** check variable is declared in global scope.It means it has access everywhere.Then even if the `IF statement` fails it should print the globally assigned value which is 1 instead of undefined.Why it prints undefined instead of 1??

**2.** main function scope doesn't have a check variable.When if fails to find check inside main function's scope ,why it doesn't look for it in global scope??

```js
  (function(){
        var check=1;
        function main(){
      if(check){
               var check=10;
         }
   document.write(check);
   }
  main();
    })();
```

Comment: Because it found a `check` variable before it reached the global scope.

Comment: it didn't found a check.it is printing undefined.

Comment: You set it equal to undefined when you did `var check=10`. :) I'm sure an answer will explain it shortly. this is a very common problem.

Comment: can you be a little more specific???

Comment: Try this for further reading on the topic: http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript only has *function scope* and something called *hoisting*. Every variable declaration inside a function gets put at the beginning of the function. Thus, your code is equivalent to

```
var check=1;
function main(){
  var check; // = undefined
  if(check){ // block doesn't create scope
    check=10;
  }
  document.write(check);
}
```

The local variable `check` shadows the outer variable `check`.

Comment: And, to fix it, simply remove the `var` before `var check=10;`

Comment: okey firstly i didn't have a check variable inside main.If check is equal to undefined and if statement finds check inside main's scope.Then it should change the value to 10.So why it is still undefined??

Comment: `check` is undefined when the if conditional is executed, therefore the if condition fails.

Comment: It's a very interesting scenario. The var inside the if conditional  makes the if conditional false. :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will look up the chain for the most local variable it can find. Basically, local scope trumps global scope.

This is one of the potential pitfalls with global scope, and is why it should be avoided, since it creates clashes with local variables.

Comment: Scope isn't a pitfall, it's by design. If we were only able to access variables declared in a local function scope plus parameters coming in to a function, libraries such as jQuery could not exist.

Comment: I don't mean to say that there aren't exceptions, but rather that it should be used sparingly.